# Making sense of R-Hive, Elastic MapReduce, RHIPE and Distrubted Text mining with R

Tags: r, hadoop

After having learned about MapReduce for solving a computer vision problem for my recent internship at Google, I felt like an enlightened person. I had been using R for text mining already. I wanted to use R for large scale text processing and for experiments with topic modeling. I started reading tutorials and working on some of those. I will now put down my understanding of each of the tools:

1) R text mining toolbox: Meant for local (client side) text processing and it uses the XML library

2) Hive: Hadoop interative, provides the framework to call map/reduce and also provides the DFS  interface for storing files on the DFS.

3) RHIPE: R Hadoop integrated environment

4) Elastic MapReduce with R: a MapReduce framework for those who do not have their own clusters

5) Distributed Text Mining with R: An attempt to make seamless move form local to server side processing, from R-tm to R-distributed-tm

I have the following questions and confusions about the above packages

1) Hive and RHIPE and the distributed text mining toolbox need you to have your own clusters. Right?

2) If I have just one computer how would DFS work in case of HIVE

3) Are we facing with the problem of duplication of effort with the above packages?

I am hoping to get insights on the above questions in the next few days

Answer (score 2):

(1) Well Hive and Rhipe dont need cluster, you can run them on single node cluster.
RHipe basically is a framework (in R language a package) which integrates R and Hadoop and  you can leverage the power of R on Hadoop. For using Rhipe you don't need to have a cluster, you can run in either way i.e. either in cluster mode or pseudo mode. Even if you have Hadoop cluster of more than 2 nodes you can still use Rhipe in local mode by specifying the property mapered.job.tracker='local'.

You can go to my site (search for) "Bangalore R user groups" and you can see how i have tried solving the problems using Rhipe, i hope you can get a fair idea

(2)Well by Hive means do you mean hive package in R? since this package is somewhat misleading with Hive (hadoop data ware house).

The hive package in R is similar to Rhipe only with some additional functionalites( i have not gone through fully)..The hive package when i saw i thought they have integrated R with Hive, but after seeing the functionality it was not like dat.

Well Hadoop data ware house which is HIVE, is basically if you are interested in some subset of results which should run through subset of data, which you normally do using SQL queries. The queries in HIVE also are very much similar to SQL queries.
TO give you a very simple example: lets say you have 1TB of stock data for various stocks for last 10 years. Now the first thing you will do is, you will store on HDFS and then you create a HIVE table on top of it. Thats it...Now fire whatever query you wish. You also might want to do some complex calculatiion also like finding simple moving average (SMA), in this case you can write your UDF (userr defined function). Besides this you can also use UDTF( User defined table generating function)

(3) If you have one system that means you are running Hadoop in pseudo mode. Moreover you need not worry whether Hadoop is running on pseudo mode or cluster mode,, since Hive needs to be installed only on NameNode, not on the data nodes. Once proper configuration is done,hive will take care of submitting the job on cluster.
Unlike Hive, you need to install R and Rhipe on all the data nodes including NameNode. But then at any point of time if you want to run the job only in NameNode you can do as i mentioned above.

(4) One more thing Rhipe is meant for only batch jobs, that means the MR job will run on the whole data set while Hive you can run on subset of data.

(5)I would like to understand what exactly you are doing in text mining, are you trying to do some king of NLP stuff like Name Entity Recognition using HMM (Hidden Markov Models), CRF(Condition Random fields), feature vectors or SVM (Support Vector machines).
Or you simple trying to to do document clustering, indexing etc
Well there are packages like tm,openNLP,HMM,SVM etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the distributed text mining with R application, but Hive can run on a local cluster or on a single-node cluster.  This can be done for experimenting or in practice, but does defeat the purpose of having a distributed file system for serious work.  As far as duplication of effort, Hive is meant to be a complete SQL implementation on top of Hadoop, so there is duplication in as much as both SQL and R can both work with text data, but not in as much as both are specific tools with different strengths.